# Notify windows phone application after a data is inserted in table using Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am totally new with Azure Mobile Services. I am actually learning from the documentation and sample codes.

I am wondering though how do you notify a the windows application (my app) if there are changes made in the table? i.e. A data inserted or updated?

Do you have any good code sample as well resource too to review this kinds of functionallity?

THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update the insert (and update) scripts for the table you want to be notified about. The tutorial at https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/push-notifications-to-users-wp8/ should have exactly the information you're looking for.

Comment: ahh just like what I watched in Build 2013. It was like 2am here when they're doing a demo with that and I'm so drowsy can't accept anymoore inputs. Thanks!